# Fixedwidthflextable header resizing

Tags: gwt, resize, flextable

I'm using `FixedWidthFlexTable` from the GWT library. and the current behavior when re-sizing any of the header columns is to increase the width of the column and decrease the size of the column next to it, so it looks like you're taking from the width of the column next to it.

Is there any way to change the header resizing behavior so that the width of the column is increased without taking space from any other columns (and in that case the width of the whole table will increase, just like the windows explorer does it for example).

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: if you're looking for that kind of behavior, why use `FixedWidthFlexTable` and not simply `FlexTable` (which implements it out of the box)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the FixedWidthFlexTable.java class where there should be a method for adjusting the columnwidth in percentage whereas currently the operation is being done through pixels this doesn't necessarily mean that the pixel implementation is wrong.The pixel implementation might be correct but I feel there should be an implementation in terms of percentage also.. algebra and not arithmetic!!!! though for ur current problem there might be a browser issue.. try testing on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was specific to ScrollTable and itsResizePolicy, solved it by setting it to UNCONSTRAINED, very newbie